# How do I extract DOM object from within textarea?

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I want to extract out an DOM object out of one of textarea which is defined.
Example :

```
<textarea id="myTextArea"><span id="sp1">some text</span></textarea>
```

Note : <span> inside <textarea> is decoded. I simply want to find a particular <span> by its id inside the textarea and instantiate an new object out of it.

As of yet, I'm trying following to no avail :

```
var spanObject = $("#myTextArea").val().find("span#sp1);
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated !

Thanks.

Comment: Please see my latest updates ! Thanks.

Comment: The return value of `val()` is a string containing your `<span>` tag, not a jQuery object. You need to convert that string into a jQuery object by nesting calls to `$()`. jQuery will then create an element tree from your string.

Comment: I'm having 'null' guys ! Even looping through all spans, I still get 'null'. What am I doing wrong? Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: as @patrick dw pointed out in my answer, you shouldn't call `find()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
$($("#myTextArea").val());
```

Comment: @patrick, you're absolutely right, an element can't `find()` itself. Answer updated.

Comment: +1 - This will work. EDIT: Sorry, deleted my comment accidentally. Anyway, yes, your corrected version is good. :o)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
var $obj = $( $( 'selector for your textarea' ).val () );
var $yourSpan = $obj.find ( '#sp1' );
```

First you create a DOM object from whatever string there is in the textarea, then you search this new DOM object (jQuery object actually) for your desired element.

Comment: +1 for the correct technique, but you should use `val` for textareas.

Comment: .val gives the value right , how come it returns..dom reference

Comment: @gov: `$(value)` creates a DOM tree using the HTML contained in the value.