# to fetch html element in textarea in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I am describing some html elements as value of thickbox and its possible to fetch that elements inside textarea

Sample

```
<textarea id="txtarea_id"><div class="div_class">country</div></textarea>
```

I need to fetch the div element inside textarea

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I extract DOM object from within textarea ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166376/how-do-i-extract-dom-object-from-within-textarea)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<!ELEMENT TEXTAREA - - (#PCDATA)       -- multi-line text field -->
```

— http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.7

A textarea element can contain only PCDATA, no elements of any kind. The code you have presented is invalid HTML.

You could have the value of a textarea be some text that could be presented as HTML:

```
<textarea id="txtarea_id">&lt;div class="div_class"&gt;country&lt;/div&gt;</textarea>
```

… but the content can only be text, not elements.

You can fetch the data using jQuery's `val()` method (or just use the standard DOM `.value`).

Comment: The question was ambiguous, I guess. OP said "I am describing some html elements as value of thickbox" and, in the end, "I need to fetch the div element inside textarea".

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's [**.val()**](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

```
alert($('#txtarea_id').val());
```

If you want to convert that text to an HTML element, use `$` and wrap it like this.

```
$($('#txtarea_id').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can not use HTML tags inside a textarea. It will be encoded and you will see "`<div class="div_class"`>country`</div`>" as the default text in your textarea.

I am wondering why are you doing this?

You can give a class to the textarea and then define css for that class.